# Java remove duplicate attribute in List<Message>

Tags: java, list

I have list of messages, class `Message` has 2 attributes as shown here:

```
class Message {
    String message;
    long time;
}
```

```
List<Message> listMessage = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A", 1);
list.add("A", 2);
list.add("B", 1);
list.add("C", 1);
list.add("C", 2);
```

I want to remove duplicate message from list but must keep the message with the longest time in List

Input

```
("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("B", 1), ("C", 1), ("C", 2)
```

Expect result

```
("A", 2), ("B", 1), ("C", 2)
```

Comment: i would sort the list using `list.sort(...)`, then use `list.iterator()` and it's `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()` methods. I am not going to do your homework for you though.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is your question? A lot of learning is trying to find a solution to a problem. I would recommend updating the question to contain how you are currently approaching the problem and what isn't working

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static class Message {
    String message;
    long time;
    
    public Message(String message, long time) {
        this.message = message;
        this.time = time;
    }
}

public static void putLatestMessage(Map<String, Message> messageMap, Message message) {
    if (messageMap.containsKey(message.message) && messageMap.get(message.message).time >= message.time) {
        return;
    } else {
        messageMap.put(message.message, message);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Message> messageMap = new HashMap<>();
    putLatestMessage(messageMap, new Message("A", 1));
    putLatestMessage(messageMap, new Message("B", 2));
    putLatestMessage(messageMap, new Message("A", 2));
    putLatestMessage(messageMap, new Message("C", 2));
    putLatestMessage(messageMap, new Message("D", 1));
}
```

This will solve your issue.

P.S - plz go through basic data structures available in Java and their use cases.